How do I get Ajax data in JavaScript for Automation?
I’m trying to write a simple script which reads one line of text from a remote server. The URL is something like:
https://ajax.internotes.net/password/?password=Test@321
This returns a simple has of a password.
Is it possible to do this in JXA? I’ve tried the usual Ajax methods using fetch() and even XMLHttpRequest(), but they’re not available.
Perhaps I can fake it with a call to the terminal?
FWIW, I’m not trying to use this for authentication. It’s just one step in longer process.

Could you review this question as an example and perhaps edit in what kind of a start you have? It’s not clear if this is a pure JavaScript question which would likely do best on stack overflow or it’s relating to Apple’s tool to run a script.

I’m not sure whether this is the best solution, but I was able to get a result with a call to curl using doShellScript().
Here is the code which replaces highlighted text with its hash:
function run(input, parameters) {
    var text = input[0].toString();

    var app = Application.currentApplication();
    app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

    var url = `https://ajax.internotes.net/password/?password=${text}`;
    var hash = app.doShellScript(`curl ${url}`);

    return hash;
}

